# numpy large array indexing crashes the interpreter

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to reference a numpy array of matrices with two arrays of indices i and j. The method i use below works fine but crashes the interpreter when dealing with extremely large arrays. I understand why this is happening but i'm too new to numpy to know of a better way to do this.

Is there any way to achieve the code below efficiently with large arrays?

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=4,suppress=True)

def test(COUNT):
    M = np.random.random_sample((COUNT,4,4,)) # Many matrices
    i = np.random.randint(4, size=COUNT)
    j = np.random.randint(4, size=COUNT)

    # Debug prints
    print M # Print the source matrices for reference
    print i # Print the i indices for reference
    print j # Print the j indices, for reference

    # return the diagonal, this is where the code fails because
    # M[:,i,j] gets incredibly large. This is what i'm trying to solve
    return  M[:,i,j].diagonal() 
    #return np.einsum('ii->i', M[:,i,j])
```

Some examples:

```
# test 1 item, easy
print test(1)

[[[ 0.4158  0.2146  0.0371  0.4449]
  [ 0.8894  0.9889  0.0961  0.7343]
  [ 0.8905  0.2062  0.1663  0.04  ]
  [ 0.691   0.1203  0.6524  0.636 ]]]
[1]    
[0]
[ 0.8894]
```

Perfect, index [1][0] of the first (and only) matrix is 0.884

```
# test 2 items
print test(2)

[[[ 0.0697  0.434   0.8456  0.592 ]
  [ 0.4413  0.8893  0.9973  0.9184]
  [ 0.7951  0.7392  0.8603  0.8069]
  [ 0.5054  0.3846  0.7708  0.0563]]

 [[ 0.7414  0.2676  0.4796  0.1424]
  [ 0.1203  0.9183  0.1341  0.074 ]
  [ 0.2375  0.3475  0.2298  0.9879]
  [ 0.7814  0.0262  0.4498  0.9864]]]
[2 3]
[1 1]
[ 0.7392  0.0262]
```

As expected, values at index [2][1] of the first matrix and [3][1] of the second are [ 0.7392  0.0262], all is well!... however....

```
# too many items!
print test(1000000)
```

Machine stalls because M[:,i,j] is simply too large from all the throw away values (all i care about is the diagonal).

I dabbled with np.einsum a little to see if it could help. But again this is all too new to me, so now i'm looking for a little help! :)

Comment: I think it would be a lot better if you had an actual use case that can be (memory) optimized, or perhaps written in a completely different way (avoiding the use of a 3D array). At the moment, you essentially just generate N random values between 0 and 1; that's easy to optimize as `random_sample(N)`, obviously. So the question is: why do you want to do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `einsum` does anything for you - you are just using it as an alternative to `diagonal`.  But try:

```
M[np.arange(COUNT),i,j]
```

This should return the desired elements without ever collecting extras.

This works because it is the equivalent of indexing with:

```
M[[0 1], [2 3], [1 1]]
```

that is, the elements

```
M[0,2,1] and M[1,3,1]
```

The other generates a `(COUNT,COUNT)` matrix, and extracts the diagonal `(COUNT,)` array from that.

Comment: nice! I'm not quite sure why this works and not ":", but this does the job!